# What does &self refer to in the Deref trait implemented on the Inner struct?

Tags: rust

I've found this piece of code on a reddit post that is very confusing to me.

```
//We'll recurse all we want, thank you very much!
#![allow(unconditional_recursion)]

use std::ops::Deref;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Outer<T: Deref<Target = Outer<T>>> {
    inner: T,
}

impl<T: Deref<Target = Outer<T>>> Deref for Outer<T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.inner
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Inner {}

impl Deref for Inner {
    type Target = Outer<Inner>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        //Look at which struct we're implementing Deref for,
        //and then read the next line very carefully.
        &self.inner
    }
}

const I: Inner = Inner {};
const O: Outer<Inner> = Outer { inner: I };

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", O.inner);
    //Could just keep adding asterisks forever!
    println!("{:?}", *O.inner);
    println!("{:?}", **O.inner);
    println!("{:?}", ***O.inner);

    println!("{:?}", O);
    //Could just keep adding asterisks forever!
    println!("{:?}", *O);
    println!("{:?}", **O);
    println!("{:?}", ***O);
}
```

Specifically here:

```
impl Deref for Inner {
    type Target = Outer<Inner>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        //Look at which struct we're implementing Deref for,
        //and then read the next line very carefully.
        &self.inner
    }
}
```

How does the function return a reference to a field that belongs to another struct? Does &self actually refer to Outer here?

(Also this code crashes every time from stack overflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there is no `inner` on `Inner`. But before giving up, the compiler thinks, "wait, is there some `Deref` implementation for `Inner`?" and of course the answer is, there is! We're writing it right now! So, what does it return? `Outer<Inner>`? Well, try to deref and find `inner` on `Outer<Inner>`! That is, `&self.inner` gets transformed into `&<Self as Deref>::deref(&self).inner`. That is [autoderef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules) in action.

Of course, since we are *already* inside `<Inner as Deref>::deref()`, we call it again, recursively... and again... and again... until we blow the stack. If you'll remove the `#[allow(unconditional_recursion)]` at the top, the compiler will warn you about that ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=37849eac6cb00cbb427e7c883e3e521e)):

```
warning: function cannot return without recursing
  --> src/main.rs:22:5
   |
22 |     fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot return without recursing
...
25 |         &self.inner
   |          ---------- recursive call site
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unconditional_recursion)]` on by default
   = help: a `loop` may express intention better if this is on purpose
```

But when you say `#[allow(unconditional_recursion)]`, you tell the compiler "trust me, I know what I'm doing" so it just shrugs and continues.

Comment: Thank you so much, this answers my questions just perfectly!!!